# pointfree style for a conditional function

Tags: javascript, pointfree, ramda.js

I would love some assistance in writing this in pointfree style.

For context: The function takes an Array of Either types and returns a Task type. The task type is rejected with any of the Either types that have the left set.  The task type is resolved if there are no Either types with the left set. This is used in this manner:

```
    Async.parallel(xs).             
        map(eachToEither).          
        chain(rejectAnyLefts).      
        fork(error, success)
```

Where in practice I would add another chain (just prior to the fork) to perform a perist.  But first I want make sure my code is idimatic as possible.  The function at hand is the rejectAnyLefts which I would like to write pointfree, but there are a couple of things throwing me to the loop.

> 1. the if
> 2. the need for storing the leftObjs value to be used in the IF and potentially the return value

```
const rejectAnyLefts = function(eitherArray){
    const leftObjs = r.filter(r.propEq("isLeft", true), eitherArray)

    const isEmpty = r.propEq('length', 0)
    return (isEmpty(leftObjs)) ?
        Task.rejected(leftObjs) :
        Task.of(eitherArray)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were only interested in capturing the first `Left` value then this could be defined using [`R.sequence`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#sequence) which will convert a `[Either a b]` into an `Either a [b]`.

```
R.pipe(R.sequence(Either.of), R.invoker(2, 'fold', Task.rejected, Task.of));
```

A `Validation` type could be used rather than `Either` which will instead combine all of the `Failure` values, however this would require the value in your `Failure` types to implement `Semigroup` to allow them to be combined.

To capture and reject all `Left` values, we can model your existing implementation in a point-free form such as:

```
R.pipe(R.partition(R.prop('isLeft')),
       R.ifElse(R.pipe(R.head, R.isEmpty),
                R.pipe(R.last, Task.of),
                R.pipe(R.head, Task.rejected)));
```

Whether this becomes more or less readable than your existing implementation is largely subjective.

Comment: Ahhh - I was considering the partition function, but couldn't think the  remainder of the code out (still new to rmada).  I was considering something like the IF in excel - which is exactly what this is.  Mentally I wasn't too far off, thanks for the assistance.  Subjectivley I don't  think this is more readable than the "pointed" implementation.  But this was more of ana cademic question for me, and I feel like my understanding was moved forward,